# how to output a feature vector machine learning classification algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, classification

In traditional machine learning classification problems, the classifier accepts an input feature vector and classifies into one of predetermined classes.

In my scenario, I need to take an input feature vector

```
Fin = (fi1, fi2, fi3.... fin)
```

and learn to output another feature vector like

```
Fout = (fo1, fo2, fo3,....fon)
```

How can this be achieved using general classifiers like ANN, decision trees or svm.

Comment: I addition, can I use feature hashing for output feature vector and train the model to learn to output this hash value for input feature vector

Comment: Hi @marc, could you share please, which technique did you apply? What are the results?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use "general classifiers", your only option is to predict each vector element individually, i.e. learn a model to predict the first feature, predict it, repeat n times.

Predicting structured outputs such as feature vectors is also possible using [statistical relational learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_relational_learning) techniques. This is a much less mature field than traditional machine learning though and harder to understand and use. In addition, there are far fewer tools available.